# Mandelbrot Set Main Shape

Tags: geometry, terminology, definition, fractals

What is the exact shape of the main component of the Mandelbrot set? I’m referring to the heart-shaped area centered at at the origin. Is there a simple way to express this shape in Cartesian or polar coordinates?

Comment: See https://sites.google.com/site/fabstellar84/fractals/cardioid and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1341171/why-does-the-boundary-of-the-mandelbrot-set-contain-a-cardioid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a [cardioid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/cardioid).  The Wikipedia article on the Mandelbrot set explains this in some detail, and even has a section titled “[main cardioid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandelbrot_set#Main_cardioid_and_period_bulbs)”:

> Upon looking at a picture of the Mandelbrot set, one immediately notices the large cardioid-shaped region in the center. This *main cardioid* is the region of parameters $c$ for which $P_c$ has an attracting fixed point. It consists of all parameters of the form
> $$c = \frac\mu2(1-\frac\mu 2)$$ for some $\mu$ in the open unit disc.

The answers at [Why does the boundary of the Mandelbrot set contain a cardioid?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1341171/why-does-the-boundary-of-the-mandelbrot-set-contain-a-cardioid) have a presentation of the cardioid's boundary that may be easier to deal with.